# Performance Testing Non Restful SpringBoot

Tags: spring-boot, performance-testing

I have a spring boot app that listens to a queue so it is non restful. Is there any easy way to get a time breakdown for the amount of time spent in each service?

Comment: Do you mean a kind of timeout?

Answer (score 0):

The options are in:

1. Use a [Profiler](https://www.baeldung.com/java-profilers) tool when running your application, this way you will be able to trace down the time even to a single function call
2. If you have an [APM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_performance_management) tool in place you can collect the same information plus metrics from the operating system, database, message broker, etc.

Just in case you need to generate messages and "feed" them to your application it could be done using i.e. [Apache JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/) tool, see [Building a JMS Testing Plan](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/building-jms-testing-plan-apache-jmeter) article for more information if needed